# Discord.io bot for node.js failing on simple script

Tags: node.js, discord.io

I ripped a basic template for the node.js discord bot that has the following code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
var fs = require('fs');

// Configure logger settings

logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
        colorize: true
});

logger.level = 'debug';


// Initialize Discord Bot

var bot = new Discord.Client({

        token: auth.token,
        autorun: true

});
```

Yesterday, when I first installed the discord.io package and ran this test script is worked fine (so I believe the authentication code is still correct unless they are temporary). However, today when I run I get the following error:

```
/home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/discord.io/lib/index.js:1906
            old = copy(client.servers[_data.guild_id].members[_data.user.id]);
                                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '938110835216236606')
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (/home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/discord.io/lib/index.js:1906:53)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Receiver.ontext (/home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at /home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:536:18
    at Receiver.applyExtensions (/home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:371:5)
    at /home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:508:14
    at Receiver.flush (/home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:347:3)
    at Receiver.finish (/home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:541:12)
    at Receiver.expectHandler (/home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:499:31)
    at Receiver.add (/home/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/nodeDiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:103:24)

Node.js v17.4.0
```

Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.